# Create test double at class (not instance) level

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my spec, I am trying to create a class constant using rspec's #double method.  The reason for a class constant is so that MockSidePolicies can have access to it:

```
describe Pages do

  PLAIN_MEDIUM = double Paper::Medium

  class MockSidePolicies
    def policy(medium)
      {
        PLAIN_MEDIUM => PLAIN_POLICY,
        ...
      }[medium]
    end
    ...
  end
```

This doesn't work:

```
undefined method `double' for #<Class:0xa0ff334> (NoMethodError)
```

I can, of course, use #double inside a #let:

```
   let(:plain_medium) = double Paper::Medium
```

But then the MockSidePolicies class won't have access to it.

How can I use rspec's #double method at the class level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*#double* is defined in the mixin RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods, so just extend the class with that mixin:

```
describe Object

    extend RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods

    FOO = double Object

    specify do
      p FOO    # => #<RSpec::Mocks::Mock:0x47404c4 @name=Object>
    end    

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to create a test double with dynamic behavior, and you don't need to create a class for that, at least in this instance.

Instead of class constants, use normal "let" variables:

```
  let(:plain_medium) {'plain medium'}
  let(:plain_policy) {SidePolicy.new}
```

And instead of a class, just make a normal test double:

```
  let(:side_policies) {double SidePolicies}
```

And then, in a *before* block, give it the desired dynamic behavior:

```
  before(:each) do
    side_policies.stub(:policy) do |medium|
      {
        plain_medium => plain_policy,
        preprinted_medium => preprinted_policy,
      }[medium]
    end
  end
```